# How can I Change VSCODE sidebar font

Tags: fonts, vscode

[image]

the sidebar font is the same ubuntu font, 
using elementary tweaks only provides 
Default, Document, Title and Monoscape fonts.

These settings don't change the vscode sidebar ubuntu font, and why the heck ubuntu font is there in vscode, please provide a solution

Answer (score 2):

VS Code is an Electron app (built using web technologies), as opposed to a native app (using GTK). I don't believe you have any control over the fonts beyond whatever settings Microsoft have exposed in the config; and it doesn't look like there is an option to change the sidebar font.

There is a GitHub issue [here](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/3702) requesting added support for changing the sidebar font, so keep an eye on that.

Answer (score 1):

`/usr/share/vscode/resources/app/out/vs/workbench/workbench.main.css`

Just edit `font-family` CSS to get different font in sidebar